# Teams Botbuilder, Why do i receive a blank conversation addObjectId?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a published app and we are working on new functionality that requires users' and conversations' aadObjectId.
When we're receiving a message on the Bot's side we see conversation.aadObjectId == null.
I've tried to add RSC permissions but it didn't help.
Anyone had the same and what should i do to get aadObjetcID?
Here's an example of my conversation data:

```
....
"serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/",
"conversation": {
    "id": "a:1Cohygr ... trunkated ... TscZ",
    "tenantId": "5df90000-0000-0000-0000-00000000c656",
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "aadObjectId": null  # WHY IS THIS NULL ?
}
....
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We tried to repro this issue, however we are able to get the conversation `aadObjectId` . https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iku8Z.png

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Can this be due to my bot app is a managed app ?

Comment: I don't think that can be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our app we needed conversation aad_object_id to get all recipients and then get their email addresses to send notification to them. I've made a workaround using this API:

```
    if turn_context.activity.channel_id == Channels.ms_teams:
        team_details = await TeamsInfo.get_team_details(turn_context)

        await turn_context.send_activity(
            f"the team aad_object_id: {team_details.aad_group_id}"
        )
```

Then you can request members from Graph:

```
/v1.0/groups/{team_details.aad_group_id}/members
```

If you need an email address of the user from direct conversation, you should use this request:

```
/v1.0/users/{user.aad_object_id}
```

I hope this will save you some time as i spent days on this and useless responses on stackoverflow regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're even seeing an `aadObjectId` on the `conversation` property - it usually appears on the `from` property, like this:

```
{
...
"from": {
        "id": "29:[long value]",
        "name": "Megan Bowen",
        "aadObjectId": "[actual AAD Object Id]"
    },
...
}
```

Comment: its a ConversationAccount class instance and if you check it, it has to contain aad_object_id. Here's a description.

    :param aad_object_id: This account's object ID within Azure Active
     Directory (AAD)
    :type aad_object_id: str

 Anyways i have figured how to sort this without aad_object_id, will post an answer.